# Чтение xlsb. Проблема установки движка pyxlsb

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, conda

Работаю в jupyter notebook.

Есть таблица в формате xlsb. 
При попытке чтения выдает ошибку:

```
in: import pandas as pd

in: print (pd.__version__) 
out: 1.0.1

in: file = pd.read_excel(filename) out:
XLRDError: Excel 2007 xlsb file; not supported
```

Прочитал [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019778/read-xlsb-file-in-pandas-python), что можно решить вопрос установкой и использованием движка  pyxlsb:

```
in: file = pd.read_excel(filename, engine='pyxlsb')
out: ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'pyxlsb'.  Use pip or conda to install pyxlsb.
```

Естественно, нужный движок отсутствует.
Решил установить через терминал, установленный в jupyter (win10):

```
PS C:\Users\User\Documents> conda update conda
PS C:\Users\User\Documents> conda upgrade conda
PS C:\Users\User\Documents> conda install pyxlsb
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current chann
els:
```

Поискал, как обойти. Попробовал [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493505/packagesnotfounderror-the-following-packages-are-not-available-from-current-cha) способ:

```
conda install -c conda-forge  pyxlsb
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
```

**Внимание, вопрос:** как ещё можно поставить в анаконду нужный пакет или какие ещё есть альтернативы для чтения байтовой таблицы?

*P.S. Я новичок в программировании. Пожалуйста, имейте это в виду, давая ответ.*

Comment: Можно попробовать через pip поставить: pip install pyxlsb

Comment: Conda при этом получит пакет?

Comment: pip пакет поставил. Однако в конде его по прежнему нет

Comment: Надо пробовать. Если в то окружение поставите, то пакет увидится. Конда просто следит за зависимостями пакетов, а так то многое можно и через pip ставить. По-хорошему, конечно, надо в conda ставить, но надо найти на каком канале есть пакет именно для вашей системы и вашей версии питона, это не всегда бывает возможно. Через pip поставить обычно проще, но может быть несовместимость с другими пакетами

Comment: Надо ставить из того окружения, которое вы используете. Возможно, нужно через pip3 ставить, если у вас 3-й питон. Тема окружений довольно запутана, я её сам не совсем понимаю. Нужно найти именно тот pip который у вас с conda поставлен и в нём установку запускать. На компьютере может быть несколько питонов запросто и у каждого своё окружение. Плюс в конде тоже может быть несколько разных окружений.

Answer (score 1):

В итоге по совету @crazyElf я установил пакет командой
`pip install pyxlsb`. После этого команда `file = pd.read_excel(filename, engine='pyxlsb')` спокойно прочла файл (только первую вкладку, но это уже другая история)

Comment: по умолчанию читается первый лист, чтобы прочесть другой лист: `df = pd.read_excel(filename, engine='pyxlsb', sheet_name='Sheet2')`

Comment: Так и сделал, спасибо. И, что важно, на выходе получаешь не датафрейм, а словарь из таблиц